# Keras Multiple “Softmax” in last layer possible?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, multiclass-classification

[image: multiple softmax in last layer]

Is it possible to implement mutiple softmaxes in the last layer in Keras? So the sum of Nodes 1-4 = 1; 5-8 = 1; etc.

Should I go for a different network design?

Answer (score 10):

I would use the functional interface.

Something like this:

```
from keras.layers import Activation, Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate

input_ = Input(shape=input_shape)

x = input_
x1 = Dense(4, x)
x2 = Dense(4, x)
x3 = Dense(4, x)
x1 = Activation('softmax')(x1)
x2 = Activation('softmax')(x2)
x3 = Activation('softmax')(x3)
x = Concatenate([x1, x2, x3])

model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=x)
```

Comment: Worth noting the cost function is also going to require similar custom work.

Comment: @NeilSlater This would be another question.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you add the solution, but I think leaving answer as-is gives the impression that OP's model-building work would be complete. But there's an equal extra amount of work for OP to do in other parts of code if they want to actually train the model. You could at least reference that requirement. Same applies to other answer . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater you are absolutely right. I have no idea why I need a different cost function. Can you tell me why this is important?

Comment: @arthurDent - because Keras' multi-class cross-entropy loss is *probably* not geared up to cope with three simultaneous true classes on each example, and the separation into groups - error in one group may result in gradients incorrectly assigned to outputs in other groups. You could just try it and see what happens . . . it may still converge, but the balance point might not be as good as having three entirely separate networks.

Comment: @arthurDent:  . . . although I'm thinking it through in more detail, and the gradient at the logit for multiclass cross entropy with softmax, which is simply $\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \mathbf{y}$ may still apply and work successfully. A normal softmax output would of course fail to learn 3 classes simultaneously, but perhaps this answer is all you need after all . . .

Comment: use of metrics e.g. `categorical_accuracy` and `predict_classes` methods may need more thought . . .

Comment: When trying this, I get `ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras 'Layer' (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x0000021C237F8C18>`. Ah, it should be `x = Concatenate()([x1, x2, x3])`.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible just implement your own softmax function. You can split a tensor to parts, then compute softmax separately per part and concatenate tensor parts:

```
def custom_softmax(t):
    sh = K.shape(t)
    partial_sm = []
    for i in range(sh[1] // 4):
        partial_sm.append(K.softmax(t[:, i*4:(i+1)*4]))
    return K.concatenate(partial_sm)
```

`concatenate` without axis argument concatenate through last axis (in our case axis=1).

Then you can include this activation function in a hidden layer or add it to a graph.

```
Dense(activation=custom_activation)
```

or

```
model.add(Activation(custom_activation))
```

You also need to define a new cost function.