# The sum of probabilities is more than 1

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training, convolutional-neural-network

I have CNN architecture for object detection ( one object in image ) in KERAS.
It has 22 Convolutional layers ( layer includes max pool , LeakyRelu and Batchnorm )

The last layes are following

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(6))
```

Basicly i want to output vector that reresents `( probability that is is ObjECT , probability that it isnt , x , y , xmax, ymax )`

I am feeding it data that has one object in it and labels

```
( 1, 0, xmin , ymin , xmax , ymax )
```

This has around 0.60% accuracy. However the sum of (isOBject + isntObject ) is greater than 1.

```
[[   1.02664185    0.34075582  231.69602966  241.59547424  280.6262207
   266.35855103]]
```

Hos is this possible.

Also when i feed network another data that does NOT have object in it and labl them

( 0, 1 , 0, 0, 0, 0 ).

I get 10% accuracy. How can it be? It has more data to learn from and added false data on top of that.

I appreciate all tips and tricks / explanation, basicly all help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use appropriate activations. If you were using softmax for those two components, they'd be constrained to sum to one. LeakyReLU not only doesn't impose this constraint: it can output any real value, so it isn't even constrained to [0,1] for those components individually.

Comment: Can i use one activations for first 2 parameters, and second for other 4?

Comment: Of course you can. Use the functional API instead of sequential, and treat it as two separate output layers: one with two softmax nodes, and one with 4 LeakyReLU or whatever.

Comment: Please.  Would like be willing go demonstrate simple example?

Comment: This is the basic idea: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/23676/4683